# Trying to get property of non-object route edit button laravel

Tags: php, laravel, devexpress

I have edit button in view.php and I have some problem route to Form edit in button with devExpress

```
{
 caption :"#",
 width:'70px',
 alignment:'center',
 cellTemplate: function (container, options) {
    $('<div/>').html(Consyst.generateEditButton(options.data.id))
         .on('click', function () {
         var url = "{{route('form-history-pjformasi', ['id'=>'', 'act'=>'2' ])}}/"+options.data.id;
          Consyst.loadForm(url);
     })
     .appendTo(container);
     }
 }
```

This is router in web.php

```
Route::get('pj/form/history/formasi/{act}/{id}',
        ['as' => 'form-history-pjformasi',
            'uses' => 'Pinjaman\PjFormasiControllers@formPjFormasiHistory',]);
```

This is myController.php

```
public function formPjFormasiHistory($act, $id)
    {
        if ($this->request->ajax()) {
               $ref =  $this->repository->getReference();
               $cmo = $this->repository->getCmoDetail($this->request->cmo_id);
               $data = $this->repository->find($id);
                $var = array(
                    'data'      => $data,
                    'action'    => 2,
                    'nama_cmo'  =>$cmo->nama_cmo,
                    'no_sk'     =>$cmo->no_sk,
                    'tgl_sk'    =>date('Y-m-d', strtotime($cmo->tgl_sk)),
                    'jabatan'   =>$cmo->jabatan
                );
                $html = \view(\Config::get('consyst.view_moduls') . $this->param['view_edit'], array('pages' => $pages,'ref'=>$ref),$var)->render();
                return \Response::json(['html' => $html]);
            }
        } 
    }
```

this is a massage error

```
Trying to get property of non-object

1.in PjFormasiControllers.php line 352
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Trying to get property of non-object', 'E:\alviyan\CitraV3\app\Http\Controllers\Pinjaman\PjFormasiControllers.php', '352', array('act' => '2', 'id' => '39488', 'ref' => object(stdClass), 'cmo' => null, 'pages' => object(stdClass), 'data' => object(PjFormasi))) in PjFormasiControllers.php line 352
```

Comment: where `$cmo` comes from

Comment: in my repository

Comment: whats on your 352 number line ? Issue is simple you are trying to get a property which is not available in $cmo object.

Comment: `dd($cmo)` and plz tell us which line is line352

Answer (score 0):

please add id

```php
Route::get('pj/form/history/formasi/{act}/{id}',
        ['as' => 'form-history-pjformasi',
            'uses' => 'Pinjaman\PjFormasiControllers@formPjFormasiHistory',]);
```

this route require `act` and `id`

```php
{
 caption :"#",
 width:'70px',
 alignment:'center',
 cellTemplate: function (container, options) {
    $('<div/>').html(Consyst.generateEditButton(options.data.id))
         .on('click', function () {
         var url = "{{route('form-history-pjformasi', ['id'=>'1', 'act'=>'2' ])}}/"+options.data.id;
          Consyst.loadForm(url);
     })
     .appendTo(container);
     }
 }
``
```